# What javascript regular expression can I use to remove HTML code?

Tags: javascript, html

I am removing HTML code in the following way, but I have used replace twice.

How do I put these two together?

```
  function removeSpecialCharacter(str) {
    return str
      .replace(/<(\/)?([a-zA-Z]*)(\s[a-zA-Z]*=[^>]*)?(\s)*(\/)?>/gi, '')
      .replace(/&nbsp;/gi, '');
  }
```

Regular expressions are too difficult

Comment: HTML is not a regular language. Regular expressions are the wrong tool. Please use an HTML parser instead. What specifically are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

try the Underscore.js utility-belt library which comes with escape and unescape methods:

_.escape(string)

Escapes a string for insertion into HTML, replacing &, <, >, ", `, and ' characters.

```
_.escape('Curly, Larry & Moe');
=> "Curly, Larry &amp; Moe"
_.unescape(string)
```

The opposite of escape, replaces &, <, >, ", ` and ' with their unescaped counterparts.

```
_.unescape('Curly, Larry &amp; Moe');
=> "Curly, Larry & Moe"
```